# How to throw an exception when a file lock fails because it's open in another program?

Tags: java, file-io, file-locking

How do I throw an exception in Java when a file lock fails because it's open in another program? If I'm trying to get a lock with

```
filelock = rf.lock();
```

Right now all it does is freeze if the file is open in another program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [FileChannel#tryLock(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#tryLock%28long,%20long,%20boolean%29) function. That should do what you need.